# Open a template file directly from controller with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs

I'm using Angular for my android application. After given time I need to open a template file. This is my app.js for the particular template file

```
.when('/tracker/',
      {
         templateUrl: 'views/tracker.html',
         controller: 'MainController'
      })
```

I want to open this `tracker.html` file directly from my MainController and I'm not sure how to do that. If you need more information let me know.

Since I'm still new to Angular any help would be appreciated to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can try linking one of your scope attributes to a modal (this would open your tracker.html as a popup and then you can define other stuffs)

```
function MainController($scope, $uibModal) {
    var modalInstance;
    $scope.open= function () {
        modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'views/tracker.html',
            controller: 'MainController'
        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've done seems sufficient, I'll explain your code snippet.

```
.when('/tracker/',...
```

The above snippet says, when a user or browser requests the URL `yourhost.com/tracker/'`, do what's following,

```
  .., {
     templateUrl: 'views/tracker.html',
     controller: 'MainController'
  })
```

Direct them to the template `views/tracker.html` and use the controller `MainController` on the specified template above.

That's the simplest explanation i could come up with. I hope navigating your browser to the link, `yourhost.com/tracker/` will show you the tracker.html template you need.

If the above fails, make sure you have correctly defined your `ng-view` directives in your index.html file (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) or watch out the browser console for any errors.